# Keep Rabbitmq running in Docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I made a Docker image with a Dockerfile. I installed Rabbitmq with a RUN command :

```
&& dnf -y --nogpgcheck install rabbitmq-server \
&& rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management \
```

I tried to make a .ini file in supervisord.d/ and even copy and start a script in the container so Rabbitmq could start, add a new user and run all the time. But when I start the container, Rabbitmq isn't running.

The init.sh file (it works well if I run it manually after going into the container) :

```
(
rabbitmq-server start & \
sleep 5 ; \
rabbitmqctl add_user admin mypass 2>/dev/null ; \
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator ; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin  ".*" ".*" ".*" ;
)
```

Now, the supervisord.d/rabbitmq-server.ini file :

```
[program:rabbitmq-server]
;directory=/usr/local/
command=/sbin/rabbitmq-server -D
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
redirect_stderr=true
priority=990
```

Note : I copied a rabbitmq.config file into the container to change listening ports too.

How could I continue to have those new ports and add this new user as I did, and manage to run Rabbitmq when the container is starting (what I can't do at this moment) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use [the standard rabbitmq image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/)?  As far as I can tell it has out-of-the-box settings for everything you're trying to do.

Comment: Because I need to use a custom image made by a co-worker. That's one thing I'm obliged to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Docker can't start this... But Kubernetes does it. And that's enough for me. If someone knows why, I'd like to hear it. But actually, I'll go further into my tests.

Thank you for your help.